# Running db:reset on Heroku results in syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, dbmigrate

I have a boolean field that seems to be causing issues. When I run `heroku run rake db:reset`, I get this as a result:

```
rake aborted!
PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ...her_email" character varying(255), "admin" boolean(255) DEFA...
                                                             ^
: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "name" character varying(255), "email" character varying(255), "other_email" character varying(255), "admin" boolean(255) DEFAULT 'f', "password_digest" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "auth_token" character varying(255), "password_reset_token" character varying(255), "password_reset_sent_at" timestamp, "plant_id" integer, "invoice" boolean)
```

Here's the migration in question:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :other_email
      t.boolean :admin, :default => false, :null => false
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm unsure why a field length is being added to a boolean field. Is there a way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `schema.rb` file, you may find there

```
t.boolean  "admin", :limit => 255
```

You can create migration

```
change_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :limit => nil
```

I guess you can also add `:limit => nil` to `create_table` migration. You may also have to run `rake db:migrate` in development environment and commit new `schema.rb` without `:limit` to production.